# How to convert image binary "string" from an API response into an image file

Tags: php, wordpress, api

I have built an API endpoint from an external server to [prevent CORS issue](https://legacydocs.hubspot.com/docs/faq/do-hubspot-apis-support-ajax-request) when using the [HubSpot Events HTTP API](https://legacydocs.hubspot.com/docs/methods/enterprise_events/http_api) to make a request.

The Events API will return an image/gif as a response. Here's an example HS Events API request:

`https://track.hubspot.com/v1/event?_n=000000001625&_a=62515&email=testingapis@hubspot.com`

And here is my created API endpoint built within WP Rest API:

```
function hs_events_api_call( $data ) {

    if ( empty( $data ) ) {
        return null;
    }

    $token = "my-token";
    $endpoint = 'https://track.hubspot.com/v1/event';
    $hubId = "my-hubid";

    $required['_a'] = $hubId;
    $required['_n'] = $data["eventid"];
    $required['email'] = $data->get_param( 'email' );

    $query_string = build_query_string($required);

    $args = array(
        'method'      => 'GET',
        'headers'     => array(
            'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $token,
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
        ),
    ); 

    $url = $endpoint.'?'.$query_string;
    
    $request = wp_remote_get( esc_url_raw( $url ), $args )["body"];

    if( empty( $request ) ) {
        return null;
    }

    $response = new WP_REST_Response($request);
    $response->set_status(200);
    $response->header('Content-Type', 'image/gif');

    return $response;
}
```

The problem with the endpoint I created is that it returns the image binary as a string. Specifically looking like this:

```
"GIF89a\u0001\u0000\u0001\u0000?\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000!?\u0004\u0001\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000,\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0001\u0000\u0001\u0000@\b\u0004\u0000\u0001\u0004\u0004\u0000;"
```

How can I convert it so it outputs as an image file, specifically, an "image/gif" type?
Or is possible at all?

Comment: Looks like it is a JSON-encoded string value, so you should be able to simply use `json_decode`.

Comment: Try the `imagecreatefromstring` method, which is documented [here](https://www.php.net/imagecreatefromstring).

Comment: What size image do you expect the given url to yield? Is that url actually going to yield a proper image or is it simply an example?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius I'm not entirely sure what size of the image will it get. Around 300B? It's 1x1 pixel GIF image used for tracking. But. I'm positive The URL is going to output a proper image. Though, the problem I'm having is that the image is stored as a string from the API's JSON response. I've no idea how to convert it and output it as an actual image/gif

Comment: That was more or less what I was getting at - it seems like a tracking pixel as you say so it will never properly render as an image. As pointed out above by @BhaumikPandhi - the `imagecreatefromstring` is worthy of investigation. Is the image string you cited the complete string?

Comment: I've tried `imagecreatefromstring` as suggested by @BhaumikPandhi. It works but the output is not exactly the same as the expected image. Some characters were off. 
Yes, the image string is the complete string.

Comment: Here's my new code with `imagecreatefromstring`. : https://pastebin.com/tyNcLE2f
It does output now to image binary. But, it's not the expected outcome. Some characters did not match.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, `file_get_contents()` solves it:

```
    $pixel = file_get_contents( esc_url_raw( $url ) );
    
    header('Content-Type: image/gif');
    echo $pixel;
```

Comment: Just a note that `file_get_contents(To-a-URL)` can sometimes be restricted on some shared servers. Use with caution as it could return a "404" or "500" error that you pump out directly to the user. And the reason why this works and not your original - in your original you asked for `'application/json'` and that's what you got. Hope that helps with your debugging.

Comment: @Robbie thanks! Yeah, I'll keep that in mind. This will only run on our server, though.